# Win 8 Pro VMware guest cannot access shared folder on W10Pro Host ("user context supplied is invalid")

Tags: shared-folders

I'm using VMware Workstation 17 Player.  After sharing a folder on the W8P Guest VM I tried accessing it from the W10P Host and got an error: "the user context supplied is invalid". The W8P VM appears in W10P's Network Places but the "username or password" is rejected, even though I have the correct credentials. In fact, I am able to use those credentials to access the W10P share from an elevated CMD Shell on the W8P VM guest (net user \...). It's just that I cannot access the share using File Explorer, Network Places, drive mapping). I made the usual compatibility tweaks to the W10P Host, covered in [this Windows doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/cannot-access-shared-folder-file-explorer) (e.g., enabling SMB 1.0, enabling Function Discover Provider Host and Resource Publication Services, enabling "Turn on network discovery" and "file and printer sharing", etc.).  So I'm baffled. Suggestions?

Comment: No issue here with VMware 17.   Make sure both Windows systems have Network Discovery, File and Print sharing, and Password Protected sharing all ON. Restart any system you change. Then try traditional mapping from a command promtpt.   NET USE S: \\ipofothermachine\folder  .   That should work.